# Why I'm not able to call the javascript AJAX function in following scenario?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, alert

My code snippet from smarty template is as follows:

```
<form name="transaction_form" id="transaction_form">
          <table class="trnsction_details" width="100%" cellpadding="5" >
            <tbody>    
              <tr>
                <td width="150"><b>Transaction Status : </b></td>
                <td class="view_details">
                <select name="transaction_status_update" id="transaction_status_update">   
                {if $transaction_status_array}
                  {foreach from=$transaction_status_array item="status"}
                  <option value="{$status}" {if $status == $user_transaction_details.transaction_status}selected="selected" {/if}>{$status|capitalize:true}</option>
                  {/foreach}
                {/if}
                </select>
              </td>       
              <td width="150">      
              </td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
     <td valign="top"><b>Remark : </b></td>
     <td><textarea name="transaction_remark" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea></td>
     <td><a class="edit_user_transaction_status" href="{$control_url}{$query_path}?op=edit_user_transaction&page={$page}&txn_no={$user_transaction_details.transaction_no}&transaction_data_assign={$user_transaction_details.transaction_data_assign}&user_id={$user_id}{if $user_name!=''}&user_name={$user_name}{/if}{if $user_email_id!=''}&user_email_id={$user_email_id}{/if}{if $user_group!=''}&user_group={$user_group}&{/if}{if $user_sub_group!=''}&user_sub_group={$user_sub_group}{/if}{if $from_date!=''}&from_date={$from_date}{/if}{if $to_date!=''}&to_date={$to_date}{/if}{if $transaction_status!=''}&transaction_status={$transaction_status}{/if}{if $transaction_no!=''}&transaction_no={$transaction_no}{/if}">Update</a></td>
     </tr>     
   </tbody>
 </table>
</form>
```

Now I want to call the following jQuery-AJAX function upon clicking on the anchor tag, but I couldn't. I tried to print the alert at the beginning of the function but that is also no getting printed. Can you help me in calling the function upon clicking the hyperlink? Thanks in advance.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//This function is use for edit transaction status
    $(".edit_user_transaction_status").click(function(e) { alert("Hello");
         e.preventDefault();
         //for confirmation that status change
         var ans=confirm("Are you sure to change status?");
         if(!ans) {
             return false;
         }  
         var post_url           = $(this).attr('href');
         var transaction_status_update = $('#transaction_status_update').val();      

         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: post_url+"&transaction_status_update="+transaction_status_update,
                 data:$('#transaction_form').serialize(),
             dataType: 'json',  
             success: function(data) {              
                 var error = data.login_error;

                 $(".ui-widget-content").dialog("close");
                //This variables use for display title and success massage of transaction update              
                 var dialog_title   = data.title;              
                 var dialog_message = data.success_massage; 
                 //This get link where want to rerdirect
                 var redirect_link  = data.href;            

                 var $dialog = $("<div class='ui-state-success'></div>")
                 .html("<p class='ui-state-error-success'>"+dialog_message+"</p>")
                 .dialog({
                     autoOpen: false,
                     modal:true,
                     title: dialog_title,
                     width: 500,
                     height: 80,
                     close: function(){                                     
                         document.location.href =redirect_link;
                     }                  
                 });                    

                 $dialog.dialog('open');                    
             }          
        });
     });
});
```

Comment: What's not working? Do you get that alert? Do you see any network traffic in your browser console?

Comment: @RGraham: The alert is not getting printed and the console is also not showing any errors.

Comment: Is the page getting redirected or there is no action at all?

Comment: Yes the page is getting redirected

Comment: Remove the href from <a> tag and place the url in some other attribute as rel="YOUR URL" and check it. In Jquery, get the attribute as .attr('rel') instead of href.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using `Smarty`

You need to add `JavaScript` block between

```
{literal}
    // your javascript or jquery code
{/literal}
```

Comment: Ye it is inside of {literal}{/literal} tags.